# Correlation between different variables and among the group

Tags: correlation, group-differences, independence

I'm not a statistician, just a learner and facing problem in my research.

I performed experiment on 25 subjects and collected data from 3 different locations (muscles, say A, B, C). The experiment was performed till task failure, hence every subject's time to task failure is different (30 sec, 45, sec, 58 sec etc etc). I divided the whole duration (of each subject) into 14 equal parts. Each part have 1 value (mean RMS). Literature shows and my data also suggests that this mean RMS tend to increase with time i.e. mean RMS of 1st part is smaller then 2nd, 2nd is smaller then 3rd and so on (but this is ideal case, there are many variations).

From literature review, I came to know that there exists some inter-dependency among the three muscles, they follow some compensation strategy (if one muscle cannot perform to its 100%, other muscle participate for its work). Following this hypothesis, I expect that at certain point in time, mean RMS of muscle "A" (variable 1 of group 1) increase at relatively lesser rate and at the same point, mean RMS of muscle "B" (variable 1 of group 2) or muscle "C" (variable 1 of group 3) increase at slightly higher rate, thus showing the compensation strategy.

Which tool/technique can be used to see such correlation. I'm using SPSS 20.[image]

I can't attach the data file as i could not find option, hence attaching the image of data.

any suggestion, comment, solution is welcome and please consider me as novice in statistics.

Answer (score 0):

After digging back into literature, and talking to experts, i found the solution.

take the mean for variable 1 for all 25 subjects (take care of outliers) for muscle A, mean of variable 2 for all 25 subjects for muscle A and so on upto variable 14.

take the mean for variable 1 for all 25 subjects (take care of outliers) for muscle B, mean of variable 2 for all 25 subjects for muscle B and so on upto variable 14.

take the mean for variable 1 for all 25 subjects (take care of outliers) for muscle C, mean of variable 2 for all 25 subjects for muscle C and so on upto variable 14.

We will have 3 plots (graphs), and can compare them easily.